# Mean of samples from Exponential distribution

Tags: statistics

I please ask someone to check if my calculations are right.

I have $X_1, ..., X_n$ from a $\mathcal{E}(\lambda): f(x, \lambda) = \lambda e^{-\lambda x}$,
$\mathcal n = 50, {\lambda} = 3$.
I have to find $\mathcal \alpha $ such that $P(\bar{X} \le 1) = \alpha$, where $\bar{X}$ is the sample mean; i did:
$$Y=\sum_{i = 1}^{n} X_i$$
$$Y \sim \Gamma (n, 1/\lambda)$$ 
$$\bar{X} = \frac{1}{n} Y \sim \Gamma(n, \frac{1/\lambda}{n})$$
I do not know how to proceed further. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you forgot that they tell you that $n = 50$, $\lambda = 3$. Also, I will be a little more explicit.

$$P(\bar X\leq  1) = P(Y\leq n) = P(Y\leq 50)$$
where $Y$ is defined like you did. To me $Y\sim \text{Gamma}(n, \lambda)$, which implies a pdf 
$$f_Y(y) = \frac1{\Gamma(n)}\lambda^ny^{n-1}e^{-\lambda y}.$$
The cdf of the gamma distribution is well-known, 
$$P(Y\leq y) = 1-e^{-\lambda y}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{(\lambda y)^k}{k!}.$$
So you can plug in the values and get 
$$\alpha = 1-e^{-3\cdot 50}\sum_{k=0}^{49}\frac{(3\cdot 50)^k}{k!}.$$
W|A gave something like $0.99999999999999999999925878991$.

We can also try a normal approximation: $\mu = 50/3, \sigma^2 = 50/9$, and so
$$P(Y\leq 50)\approx P\left(Z\leq\frac{50-\mu}{\sigma}\right) = \Phi(14.14213562)$$
where $\Phi$ is the standard normal cdf.